# Identifying Cataphora and Anaphora using the Stanford Parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, jnlp, coreference-resolution

Can the Stanford Parser find instances of cataphora and anaphora in a given set of sentences?

Are there any alternative open-source (or proprietary) software packages that are capable of coreference resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stanford Parser can't do this, but the [coreference resolution system](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml) packaged in Stanford's [CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) can.